# Singular Values of an $n$ dimensional matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, python, singular-values

I am interested in calculating the maximum singular value of an $n$ dimensional matrix in python. Can I reshape this matrix as a $2$-D matrix and calculate its operator norm? Are the singular values of a matrix independent of its shape?

Comment: There are several ways to generalize singular value decomposition to order $n$ tensors.  See, for instance, [HOSVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition)

Comment: It's clear that singular values will not be independent of shape.  For instance, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\1}
$$
do not have the same singular values